# getString() is reading all values from one field

Tags: java, html

I'm not sure why my getString() is responding in this way. Sorry for the incomplete code, I just want to know why the problem is like that. For my HTML side, the table will generate the amount of rows according to the `${fruits}` which is a ArrayList from the doGet() method. I'm using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` because it actually takes in a file but i shorten my codes just to not confuse even further.

```
         <form id="config_form" action="Fruits" method="Post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <table id="myTable">
            <c:forEach items="${fruits}" var="val" varStatus="count">
                 <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <td>    
                           <input type="text" name="fruit" id="fruit" value="${val.fruitname}">
                        </td>
                         <td>     
                           <input type="password" name="passphrase" id="passphrase" value="${val.passphrase}">
                         </td>
                         <td>
                     </tr>
                 </tbody>
            </c:forEach>
         </table>
         </form>
```

This is code from the doPost() method where it will retrieve the values from the textfield from the HTML. The problem is that it will take it the values from the field accordingly until it reaches the 2nd row where it will take all of the values from one field rather than one value from a field.

For example, it starts with the "fruit" field and will take in `{"fruitname":"apple"}` first and follow by `{"passphrase":"123"}` from the first row and when it reaches the second row it starts to take in all of values `{"fruitname":"apple", "passphrase":"123"}` from the "fruit" field. I do not know why it works for the first row but not the second

```
    DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
    List<FileItem> uploadItems = null;


    uploadItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

    for (FileItem uploadItem : uploadItems) {
                if (uploadItem.isFormField()) {
                    String fieldName = uploadItem.getFieldName();
                    if(fieldName.equals("fruit"))
                    {
                        String fruitname= uploadItem.getString();       
                        newOutput.put("port",port);  //newOutput is a JSONObject
                    }
                    else if(fieldName.equals("passphrase"))
                    {
                        String passphrase = uploadItem.getString();
                        newOutput.put("passphrase",passphrase);
                    }
            }
        }
        arr_Output.add(newOutput);     //arr_Output is a JSONArray Object
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `<td>` close in your code. It is located before `</tr>`. Try to delete it. You have to do some thing like this :

```
     <form id="config_form" action="Fruits" method="Post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table id="myTable">
        <c:forEach items="${fruits}" var="val" varStatus="count">
             <tbody>
                 <tr>
                    <td>    
                       <input type="text" name="fruit" id="fruit" value="${val.fruitname}">
                    </td>
                     <td>     
                       <input type="password" name="passphrase" id="passphrase" value="${val.passphrase}">
                     </td>
                 </tr>
             </tbody>
        </c:forEach>
     </table>
     </form>
```